# Why vendor folder's size drops from 100MB to 15MB after pushing it to bitbucket git repository?

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-4, bitbucket, composer-php

We usually kept `vendor` folder in `.gitignore` but had to disable it since we have no ssh access on our production server and we need to run `composer update` time to time.

So, we came up with an idea about **removing `.gitignore` on vendor folder**, doing `composer update` on our local computers, pushing everything to repository and deploying it via `FTP` to our production server. (We use `DeployHQ` for doing Repository->Production transfer.)

However, right now my local project folder size is 100MB and `Bitbucket` repository size is only 20MB. My local vendor folder is around 90MB, in repository, it is just few megabytes.

When checking, I came across those values on `Bitbucket` repository:

```
vendor / doctrine /
    annotations
        cache → 89493d2c6e [89493d2c6e]
        collections → 3db3ab843f [3db3ab843f]
        common → c4255b9fbd [c4255b9fbd]
        dbal → 3253f7a1c1 [3253f7a1c1]
        inflector → 8b4b3ccec7 [8b4b3ccec7]
        lexer → bc0e1f0cc2 [bc0e1f0cc2]
```

In my local vendor folder, I see Doctrine's classes and PHP files.

So I would like to ask few things;

1. Why is this happening and what does those annotations means? (Can we relate them to symlinks? e.g Git knows it is Doctrine, so it symlinks to Doctrine's repository, and will download those files from Doctrine's repository on `git pull`?)
2. Can we safely replace our 90MB of vendor folder in production with 5MB vendor folder on our git repository? (By doing git pull on production, or copying repository folder via FTP to production.)
3. How do you deal with vendor folder yourself? Keeping it on `.gitignore` and doing composer update commands via SSH on production, or pushing them to your git repository and push your repository into production server? Also, which one is better?

Thank you.

Ps. Neither git or composer is installed on production server.

Ps. Our upload speed is very low and uploading 90MB will take a rougly a hour. Let me also note this, because we look for the quickest alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Essentially you are correct, bitbucket knows they are git repositories in your vendor folder so simply links them to the respective repositories so it does not duplicate.
   To really get to understand the annotations look into [Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)
2. No, the 5MB version is so small because it does not contain the actual code, things will break if you try to use it ;)
   try running `git submodule init` then `git submodule update` to see it inflate!
3. You should not be doing `composer update` on your production server, instead do it on your staging server (or even beforehand on your local env if your testing doesn't have ssh either [which really it shouldn't since it's meant to mock your prod env]) and if that works fine then you push the code up to the production server. Doing a `composer update` on the production server is risky at best.

Comment: That's basically what we do right now. (except staging server because we don't have one, just development to production right now.) However, 90MB vendor folder becomes 5MB on repository and I wonder why.

Comment: So what's the proper deploment way should be? I mean, I understand we need to push our vendor folder to git, but what about pushing them to production? We need to install git and issue git pull in production?

Comment: Since you don't have a staging/testing server I imagine you are just pushing the code straight from your dev machines? If so, you don't need to commit your vendor folder, just run `composer install` on your dev machine and push the vendor folder up from there. really to answer that question properly I would need to know how you are deploying you code.

Comment: First one is, copying entire project folder from dev machines to production via FTP, but it's bad because we have low upload speed. Second one is using DeployHQ to handle deployment. DeployHQ takes our repository and pushes it to production via FTP, but I don't know how it pushes the vendor folder. I don't know if it automatically converts 5MB vendor folder to 90MB using git itself. If it doesn't, third option would be installing git on production server and issuing git pull manually. We have a bad deployment practices so I'd like to get some information from you.